# MySQL what would the best approach to ranking highest to lowest possible match?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, search

I have a MySQL database I'm searching through. Lets say this is a database of people. When querying for a specific record, it is possible to find a match 100% on each attribute. But querying the database to find closest match on probability (closest matches on table attributes) is more of the strategy.

In this scenario, does it make sense to create a temporary table (much like a tally-sheet) to indicate what attributes match/what attributes are present? What is the typical approach to doing advanced searches on database like this?

**Example (below) of a hypothetical stored Procedure**

*parameters are just to exemplify how I would search. I'm **not** concerned how to perform my selects. Question is about approach, strategy, technique *

```
call FindPerson ("Brown Eyes", "Brown hair", "Height:6'1", "white", "Name:Joe" ,"weight180", "Age 34" "sex m");

RESULT TABLE
NAME  AGE HEIGHT WEIGHT HAIR  SKIN  sex  RANK_MATCH
Joe   32  6'1    180    Brown white m    1
Mike  33  6'1    179    Brown white m    2
James 31  6'0    179    Brown black m    3
```

Comment: I'm interested to see what people respond with. I've had this question in the past.

Comment: What do you mean by closest match? Is it that you want two find records with attribute that sound similar to a given string?

Comment: Are you talking about a 'predefined tag matching' or 'text matching'?

Comment: Of course I'm going to be using "BETWEEN VALUES" on age using "LIKE" on names and WHERE on attributes like sex and also bunch of crazy unions and joins. But how should I be tallying to find probability on closet matches?

Comment: Basically it's like a game of guess who and you want to know what the best way to calculate the probability that a given query is actually referring to a given person or set of people.

Comment: From a naive standpoint, just add one to the score per row for every match found. If you favor Name or Weight more, then make them worth more (2 or 3). To keep speed up, I'd recommend using integers (floating point calculations can be slower on some architectures, up to 4 times slower).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just out of my mind. You can create your own score and sort by it. Something like

```
SELECT `id`,
  (IF(`age`=32,1,0)+IF(`height`="6'1",1,0)+...) as  `score`
FROM `people`
HAVING `score` > 0
ORDER BY `score` DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

With this, you can handle every field with its own comparison, and also weight the individual attributes by not just add `1` but `2` or more.
But I'm quiet not sure, how performant this is.

Answer (score 2):

The approach I would use would be to create a scoring function (your stored proc) that would evaluate the given input's standard distance from the mean.

In the proc, you would judge each criteria in a fashion similar to:

```
INPUT AGE: 32
calculate MEAN of AGE WHERE (sex = m): 34.5
calculate STANDARD DEVIATION of AGE WHERE (sex = m): 2.5
calculate how many STDEVs 32 is from the 34.5 (also known as z-score): 1
```

Repeat this process for all numeric datatypes, summing them and ORDER BY the sum.

In doing so, the following schema change would be required: height changed from foot/inch form to strictly inches.

Depending on your needs, you may also consider coming up with an arbitrary scale for sex and skin color/hair color.  Of course, you may think that measures like these should NOT be factored in because of how drastically it would change the scoring function. If you chose to, you'd have to find some number that would be added to the above SUM...but it's hard because nominative variables don't translate easily into these kinds of things.

If you find that haircolor/skin color is able to be usefully transferred into say, the continous color spectrum, your scoring tidbit would be the same...color value of input vs color value of means and standard deviations.

The query that would find your matches would be something to the effect of:

```
SELECT
 ABS(INPUT_AGE - AVG(AGE)) / STD(AGE) AS age_z,
 ABS(INPUT_WT - AVG(WT)) / STD(WT) AS wt_z,
...
 (age_z + wt_z + ...) AS score
FROM `table`
ORDER BY score ASC
```

Comment: As a sidenote, all numerical variables can be handled strictly in a query, rather than a stored proc; a stored proc might be necessary though for the 'named' variables, like hair and eye colors, since they would presumably require some more complex logic than you'd want to put in a query.

Comment: P.P.S., my provided scoring function does a simple summation of age_z, wt_z, height_z, but you can choose other methods of interpreting this distance, such as AVG(x, y, z) or SUM(1.5*x, y, z) to give each factor additional weight.